# MIPS Assembly (MARS 4.5): floating point arithmetric answer is weird

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm making a MIPS program to calculate 5.4xy - 12.3y + 18.23x - 8.23y where x and y are inputs from console. However, the result is too weird. Here is my code:

```
.data
    promptX: .asciiz "Enter x: \n"
    promptY: .asciiz "Enter y: \n"
    result: .asciiz "Result: "
    first: .float 5.40
    second: .float -12.30
    third: .float 18.23
    fourth: .float -8.23
.text

    # Print prompt to input x
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, promptX
    syscall

    # Get x, store in f2
    li $v0, 7
    syscall
    mov.d $f2, $f0

    # Prompt input y
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, promptY
    syscall

    # Get y, store in f4
    li $v0, 7
    syscall
    mov.d $f4, $f0


    # f6 = xy
    mul.d $f6, $f2, $f4

    # load 5.4 to f8
    lwc1 $f8, first

    # f6 = 5.4xy
    mul.d $f6, $f6, $f8

    # load -12.3 to f8
    lwc1 $f8, second
    # f8 = -12.3y
    mul.d $f8, $f8, $f4


    # f6 = 5.4xy - 12.3y
    add.d $f6, $f6, $f8

    # load 18.23 to f8
    lwc1 $f8, third
    # f8 = 18.23x
    mul.d $f8, $f8, $f2
    # f6 = 5.4xy - 12.3y + 18.23x
    add.d $f6, $f6, $f8

    # load -8.23 to f8
    lwc1 $f8, fourth

    # f6 = 5.4xy - 12.3y + 18.23x + (- 8.23)
    add.d $f12, $f6, $f8

    # Print answer
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, result
    syscall

    li $v0, 2
    syscall


    # End program
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

When I input x =  2.13 and y = 2.13 it returns 1.26719E-10, where it should be 28.90016. I recheck the code many times but still don't know why. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
.data
    promptX: .asciiz "Enter x: \n"
    promptY: .asciiz "Enter y: \n"
    result: .asciiz "Result: "
    first: .double 5.40
    second: .double -12.30
    third: .double 18.23
    fourth: .double -8.23
.text

    # Print prompt to input x
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, promptX
    syscall

    # Get x, store in f2
    li $v0, 7
    syscall
    mov.d $f2, $f0

    # Prompt input y
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, promptY
    syscall

    # Get y, store in f4
    li $v0, 7
    syscall
    mov.d $f4, $f0


    # f6 = xy
    mul.d $f6, $f2, $f4
    #mul.d $f2, $f4, $f6

    # load 5.4 to f8
    l.d $f8, first

    # f6 = 5.4xy
    #mul.d $f6, $f6, $f8
    mul.d $f6, $f6, $f8

    # load -12.3 to f8
    l.d $f8, second
    # f8 = -12.3y
    mul.d $f8, $f8, $f4


    # f6 = 5.4xy - 12.3y
    add.d $f6, $f6, $f8

    # load 18.23 to f8
    l.d $f8, third
    # f8 = 18.23x
    mul.d $f8, $f8, $f2
    # f6 = 5.4xy - 12.3y + 18.23x
    add.d $f6, $f6, $f8

    # load -8.23 to f8
    l.d $f8, fourth

    # f6 = 5.4xy - 12.3y + 18.23x + (- 8.23)
    add.d $f12, $f6, $f8

    # Print answer
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, result
    syscall

    li $v0, 3

    syscall


    # End program
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

You were mixing precisions. I made everything to be double. In the end you were trying to print a float with 2 in v0, you need 3 in v0 to print a double.

Another problem that I noticed was the way that you were loading data from memory to your registers. I switched those to l.d, and the values were loaded correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You are **mixing single- and double-precision** numbers.

- The coefficients in the `.data` section are **float**
- You read the inputs as **double**
- You load the coefficients (using `lwc1`) as **float**
- You perform the calculations (`mul.d` and `add.d`) as **double**
- You print the result as **float**

Switch everything to the same precision and your code will work correctly.